# CakePHP hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM) _deleteLinks error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two models `Product` and `Document` connected with `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation.

from Product site it looks like that:

```
class Product extends AppModel {

     public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
         'Document' => array(
             'className' => 'DocumentManager.Document',
             'joinTable' => 'documents_products',
             'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
             'associationForeignKey' => 'document_id',
             'unique' => false,
          )
     )
}
```

..and now when I call `$this->Product->delete();` in `ProductsController` I got sql error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DocumentsProduct.id' in 'field list'
SQL Query: SELECT `DocumentsProduct`.`id` FROM `kd`.`documents_products` AS `DocumentsProduct` WHERE `DocumentsProduct`.`product_id` = 3
```

Above query is created by cake 2.4.6 Model.php class when cake is trying to find all relations between this two models.
find query looks like this:

```
$records = $Model->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array($Model->escapeField($data['foreignKey']) => $id),
    'fields' => $Model->primaryKey,
    'recursive' => -1,
    'callbacks' => false
));
```

In this case `$Model->primaryKey`  should return `product_id` and I have no idea why it returns `id`

Any ideas?

Thank You in advance!!

Comment: Does the `documents_products` table have an id field, in addition to the product_id and document_id? CakePHP doesn't support composite primary keys - see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: OK, this is the point. I had additional column in `documents_products` but it was called `weight` and I didn't supposed that it could be a reason. But when a droop it everything works fine. So now.. how can I manage order of Documents connected to  Product without additional column in `documents_products` table?

Comment: You need to have an `id` primary key column. Thus, your `documents_products` must have these columns: `id`, `product_id` and `document_id`. As far as having other columns (such as `weight`), you probably want to use the [hasMany through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through) model.

Comment: Thank you @AgRizzo . Now everything works!! btw: same 'Documents' are bind to many other models so I definitively needs habtm :)